# Patent Infringement requires all claims to infringe or just one?

Tags: infrigment, granted

A product that I'm developing implements half of the 28 claims mentioned in this patent application:
https://www.google.co.il/patents/WO2014111933A1?cl=en

Am I infringing the patent if it is granted? or do I need to implement all claims to infringe it?

What is the chance of this patent actually being granted as the 1st Claim basically describes any medical records software out there ?

Answer (score 1):

Please note WIPO application is just a publication and not granted patent. if its get grant in US with same claim below situations can be made.

For US granted patents:-
In accordance of 35 U.S.C. § 271(a):-

> ...whoever without authority makes, uses, offers to sell, or sells any
>   patented invention, within the United States or imports into the
>   United States any patented invention during the term of the patent
>   therefor, infringes the patent.

On number of claims to access are defined by case law as

> To prove direct infringement, the plaintiff must establish by a
>   preponderance of the evidence that **one or more claims** of the patent
>   read on the accused device literally or under the doctrine of
>   equivalents. *Advanced Cardiovascular Sys., Inc. v. Scimed Life Sys.,
>   Inc., 261 F.3d 1329, 1336 (Fed.Cir.2001)* [Link](http://openjurist.org/261/f3d/1329)

Form Method or Process base claim, every step is to be present.

> Literal infringement requires that **each and every limitation set forth
>   in a claim appear in an accused product**. *Franks Casing Crew & Rental
>   Tools, Inc. v. Weatherford Int'l, Inc., 389 F.3d 1370, 1378
>   (Fed.Cir.2004)* [Link](http://openjurist.org/389/f3d/1370)